# Count unique rows with a criterion of multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique, array-formulas

The formula in B2:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(C3:D, C3:C=TRUE, D3:D=TRUE), TRUE)
```

[image]

- Should count how many rows have at least one TRUE value in **either** column C or D
  (in the picture the checkboxes in the range C3:C5, D5 are TRUE).
- In the case of a row with both columns TRUE it should still count the row as 1.

But this formula counts a row only if in both columns C and D there's a TRUE value and in that case the row is counted as 2.

.

I have also tried

```
=FILTER(C3:D, OR(C3:C=TRUE, D3:D=TRUE))
```

but gives the error:
**#N/A FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 50498, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.**

What formula can I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FILTER` function performs an AND between the conditions, to simulate an OR you can add them instead.

```cpp
=ROWS(FILTER(C3:D,C3:C+D3:D))
```

Note that the `=TRUE` is redundant since the values are already booleans.

You could also use `SUMPRODUCT`, like this:

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(C3:C+D3:D>0)
```

Comment: The first problem gives a #N/A error when no rows have a TRUE value.
The second formula works fine.

Comment: You can use `IFNA()` to address it.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=countif(index(C3:C+D3:D),">0")
```